# Can I say " a was-winning situation"?

Tags: compounds, compound-nouns

I wanted to say:

> it is a hard feeling to stalemate at a winning situation

and since stalemate is not a winning so I wanted to use "a was-winning" to indicate that it was winning before it became a stalemate.

Is that right? What is the best expression to express that meaning?

Comment: Do you mean "It is hard to achieve a stalemate when you are at an advantage"? Or is it "It is hard when you have an advantage, but then your luck fails you and you wind up in a stalemate"?

Comment: "Was-winning" isn't something I encountered before. New "word" for me.

Comment: @copperkettle i meant its a hard feeling to stalemate at a was-winning situation.. forgot to write hard feeling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you right, I would write something like

> It feels hard to wind up in a stalemate when you **had the advantage**.

Example of usage ([chess.about.com](http://chess.about.com/od/tipsforbeginners/a/Simplification-In-Chess.htm))

> In chess, simplification works much the same way. Sure, you could try to continue pressing your advantage and win with style, but by simplifying, you take away any risk of allowing your opponent to get back into a game they have no business winning. Just be sure you only do this when you are certain the simplified position you’ll reach still gives you a big enough advantage to win the game – there’s nothing worse than simplifying into a drawn (or even losing!) position when you **had the advantage**.

---

Another possible option:

> It feels hard to wind up in a stalemate **after having been in a winning position**.

or

> It feels hard to wind up in a stalemate **after being in a winning position**.

---

Do not hurry to accept the answer, I'm not a native speaker of English, there could be better options in native heads.

Comment: I think *winning position* is okay. One possibly more idiomatic phrase is *[having the upper hand](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/the-upper-hand)*.